# No Function Found on type: org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionUtils

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm migrating `java7` to `Jakarta EE 8` and updating the `primefaces` from version 6.2 to 10, however when executing the project I get this error:

> Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
> java.lang.RuntimeException:
> com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.lang.Exception: No
> Function Found on type:
> org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionUtils with signature:
> javax.faces.component.UIComponent resolveComponent(java.lang.String,
> javax.faces.component.UIComponent)|#]

Comment: This seems to be some kind of classpath or dependency problem. `SearchExpressionUtils.resolveComponent(String, UIComponent)` was added in PrimeFaces 8 and up. Almost sounds like you have an old version of the `SearchExpressionUtils` class loaded. Check your dependencies and what is actually being loaded.

Comment: Especially if you are using an EAR file it might be you have multiple PF JAR's loaded.

Comment: I managed to solve it, the problem was that in the Payara folder the primefaces lib was out of date. Thanks a lot for the help.